# The so-what-ishness

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'the so-what-ishness' in the following sentence? 'What makes it so irksome is the so-what-ishness of this rather brandnew restaurant.'

Comment: See also *meh*.

Comment: I suggest *whateverishness*.

Comment: *ho-humitude* and *dull-osity*

Comment: Did this sentence come from this review? http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/restaurants/10321252/Union-Street-Cafe-London-restaurant-review.html  If so, you should include the link to it in your question.

Comment: The Dude abides.

Answer (score 3):

"So what?" is a response that (with the right intonation) conveys a sense of being unimpressed by, of not seeing anything special in what what just said or indicated.

So here, "so-what-ishness" might reasonably be replaced by "unimpressive nature".

---

I don't mind coinages - like "so-what-ishness" - but "rather brandnew" seemed a very odd coupling to me.

Comment: I think "so-what-ishness" describes the attitude of the restaurant. They do not care or are indifferent in their attitude. If someone says this is quite unconventional they will answer "So what?".

Comment: It could also be about attitudes, but the suggested original article doesn't carry that impression.

Answer (score 2):

"So-what-ishness" (though not an established word--hyphenated or not) means displaying an attitude of, "*so what*!" (notice this is not a question but a statement), and "*so what*" means: "*I don't care*!" This attitude conveys *indifference*, *apathy*, and a *terminally hip* posture.

> **INDIFFERENCE**
>
> **1**: the quality, state, or fact of being indifferent 
>   **2 a**: archaic: lack of difference or distinction between two or more things 
>   **b**: absence of compulsion to or toward one thing or another
>
> **Related to INDIFFERENCE**
>
> *Synonyms* apathy, casualness, complacence, disinterestedness, disregard, incuriosity, incuriousness, insouciance, nonchalance, torpor, unconcern
>
> [**Merriam-Webster Dictionary *online***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifference)
>
> **APATHY**
>
> **1**: lack of feeling or emotion: impassiveness 
>   **2**: lack of interest or concern: indifference
>
> **Related to APATHY**
>
> *Synonyms* affectlessness, emotionlessness, impassiveness, impassivity, insensibility, numbness, phlegm
>
> **And, last but not least, some cultural slang**
>
> **Terminally *hip*** or **Terminally *cool***: so incredibly laid back, disengaged, and lethargically uncaring and cool (usually in a contrived or *studied* way) that one is liable ultimately to die (literally expire) from lack of participation in one's own environment
>
> *“Dirk is terminally hip: just look at him lying on the floor with his eyes shut during the dance, while all those women are flirting with him.”*
>
> [**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=terminally+hip)
>
> **Hip**: Cooler than cool, the pinnacle of what is "it". Beyond all trends and conventional coolness. Not to be mistaken for "deck".
>
> *"Stay away from the tacky velvet-rope MTV frat-boy clubs on the beach. Check out this party downtown instead, it's gonna be hip."*
>
> [**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hip)

Comment: +1 I really enjoyed "Terminally hip". Haven't heard it yet! but you could maybe, for the sake of answering, describe that the question "so what" conveys indifference. Hence; So-what-ishness" describes an attitude of indifference or "terminal hipness".

Comment: Thanks! @AverageGatsby - didn't I do that!?

Comment: it might be seen as a logical conclusion that this is what you mean but I cannot even find the phrase "so what" in your answer.  just a minor sentence prior to the deffinition of indifference maybe?^^

Comment: Oh! @AverageGatsby - I didn't think to include "so what" because it's embedded in "*so-what-ishness*". So I'm *assuming* (and you know what thy say about assumptions!) the OP will notice that. Where you from?

Comment: well, in that case I can't find "so-what-ishness" in your answer ;). in the end I agree that it isn't necessary buut... Germany, currently living in Denmark.

Comment: @AverageGatsby - how's that? And, by the way, your English is pretty *durn* good! Love Denmark!

Comment: I just love english lit. and the language itself. It probably has its flaws to the native ear but thanks!

Comment: @AverageGatsby - especially the flowers!

Answer (score 0):

There is an expectation of others to be 'fault tolerant', when one says 'so what?'.  It goes in the line of
X: XYZ lost the match
Y: So what?

There is also an air of 'downplaying' (not necessarily 'dismissive').